# analog to MySQL's DATE_SUB / INTERVAL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In MySQL the following will tell you what the date was a month ago:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

The [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9544).

How can this be done in SQL Server?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE());
```